# HTML5 website to support different screen resolutions

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a website with one `<div>`. I need to design this screen to support all screen resolutions (for mobile devices, laptops, and also surface). It works well with my screen while zooming, but when I try to open the website with a laptop, the horizontal and vertical scrollbars automatically comes with my page.  Can anyone help me avoid scrollbars appearing with different screen resolutions?

Style I'm using:

```
<style>
div
{
    background-image: url('../Maps/Plan.png');
    width: 1514px;
    height: 960px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 190px;
    border: 2px groove;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.container
{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 1514px;
    height: 960px;
}
.container:before, .container:after
{
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You have a fixed width of 1514px, you need to mention width in percentage (100%) to have responsive website to work on all resolutions and devices. You can make use of CSS media queries for styling in different resolutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Foundation` or `bootstrap` `(grid system)` it'll take care all about for you.

Answer (score -1):

Reading your question I came to believe that you don't really know how to style a website. Therefore consider using a tutorial.
To learn how to code I would suggest to visit http://www.codecademy.com.
This is a great place to start, its free and it won't take so long to learn everything you need.